# Error compiling Octave in Centos 7

Tags: qt, octave

Here is a list of the steps that I did in order to attempt to install Octave 4.2.1 in Centos 7 (repo version is 3.8.2 which is really old now)

```
1)   yum update
2)   yum-builddep -y octave
3)   yum -y install qt-devel mercurial gcc-c++ lapack-devel libtool
4)   yum -y install epstool transfig pstoedit qscintilla-devel 

(NOTE: First problem was right here as there is NO pstoedit in Centos 7, as far as I know)

5) sudo yum install bzip2-devel atlas-devel libsndfile-devel portaudio-devel GraphicsMagick-c++-devel
6)  ln -s /usr/lib64/atlas/libtatlas.so /usr/lib64/libatlas.so (One of the tutorials recommended doing this to fix a place where a library was being searched for or something like that. It seemed harmless enough)
7) wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-4.2.1.tar.gz 
8) tar-xvf octave-4.2.1.tar.lz
9) cd octave-4.2.1
10) export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk
11) ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/octave/versions/4.2.1
12)  make -j4
```

It failed with this error:

```
In file included from libgui/src/settings-dialog.cc:31:0:
libgui/src/ui-settings-dialog.h:13:29: fatal error: QtWidgets/QAction: No such file or directory
 #include <QtWidgets/QAction>
```

Has anyone come up with this problem and has some workaround or solution? Thanks

Comment: I assume this means callling make and not just make -j4, right?

Comment: ./configure was fine? Everything found?

Comment: I didn't see any problem. I have tried with make as suggested and it is still going. So I don't know, maybe that fixed it? I'll report back as soon as it finishes...

Comment: After attempting a make I got these beautiful series of errors: https://pastebin.com/WWETebTk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QtWidgets/QAction` is specific to Qt5, and it seems that when you executed `yum-builddep -y octave` it got dependencies for Qt4. Configure octave with the option `--with-qt=4`. Another option is to install `qt5` libraries and its devel files, configure `--with-qt=5`, and make.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that? Or rather where do I use the option? In the ./configure step?

Comment: `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/octave/versions/4.2.1 --with-qt=4`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it

Comment: Dude! You are THE man!! Yes. This worked!. Any ways that I can build it using qt5? I'd like to try to do that before getting it installed

Comment: Both of these are installed. I'll try to specify --with-qt-5 and see what happens.

Comment: No, that'll not work. You should also install devel files for Qt widgets and something else, look in your repos (I'm on Ububtu).

Comment: I think I got it! When I did the configure I got this warning: "one or more of the Qt utility programs moc, uic, rcc, and lrelease not found; disabling Qt GUI" Which makes total sense with the error that I got later. Can you tell me what I can try to install in order to get these?

Comment: I found this: `yum whatprovides "*/qt5"` - execute it and install what seems to be important.

Comment: Yeah!! I figured the package qt5-qttools-devel looked important. I've installed that and the message changed yet again to QScintilla library not found. However I have them installed. It must be another case of the configure not looking for it where it should be.... I try the soft link approach. But it would help to know where the configure is looking for it

Comment: Install QScintilla for Qt5

Comment: It seems it is already installed. I have just found the library it is looking for that I can't figure out where the configure file is looking for it....

Comment: And is `-devel` for it installed?

Comment: Yes both (normal and devel). The thing is the library is named differently. I'm starting to think there is NO QScintilla for qt5 in centos....

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use Flatpack to install the latest version of Octave without any hassle:

```
flatpak install flathub org.octave.Octave
flatpak run org.octave.Octave
```

CentOS 7 already comes with built-in Flatpack app, but your distro doesn't have one you can install it:

```
sudo yum install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

Official website:
https://flatpak.org/setup/